# How to define one side operators in c++?

Tags: c++, struct, operators

How to define one side operators like `++` or `--` in c++?

for example we want to define `a##` to do `(a % 45) + 2`
[It is just an example]

Comment: `##` is a preprocessor directive and can not be overloaded

Comment: There is no `##` operator in C++. You can't make up custom operators, only [overload predefined operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). As for `++` and `--`, they are formally known as [increment/decrement operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec)

Comment: You can't *add* any operators at all, and you can't overload operators for primitive types.

Comment: To define `a##`, you'll need to create your own language.  Your new language could be C++ like.  Creating a language is a big undertaking.  Toy languages can take a few months to write; (empirically) industrial strength languages take a decade or more.

Comment: The common name for the "one-sided" operators would be **_unary_** operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `operator ++()` (prefix increment operator)
and `operator ++(int)` (postfix increment operator)

Same for `operator --`.

```
class Example
{
public:
   int a = 0;

   Example& operator++() { a = (a % 45) + 2; return *this; } // ++ex;
   Exampleoperator++(int) { Example tmp = *this; ++(*this); return tmp; } // ex++;
};
```

There is no `operator ##`.